# Access Guerrilla Mail account via Telnet/SMTP client

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to *read* emails from a [Guerilla Mail](https://www.guerrillamail.com/) account that has 'expired'

–Based on the [Guerrilla Mail documentation](https://www.guerrillamail.com/about), past email addresses are not reused or destroyed, so they should be accessible:

> "all addresses work all the time, they never expire"

–Guides like [this](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404584/sending-or-viewing-emails-using-telnet#4) try to give instruction on how to Telnet into a mail server, but at least on OSX, commands such as 'user' and 'pass' are not recognised, and Guerrilla Mail server at mail.guerrillamail.com does not recognise commands such as AUTH LOGIN.